# How to create 10 buttons by for loop

Tags: java, android

**Android-Java**
How can I create 10 buttons by for loop for Android platform.
 I've tried a lot but failed.
I've tried like this.

```
AbsoluteLayout al = …………
Button btn = new Button(MyActivity.this);
btn.setWidth(20);
btn.setHeight(6);
for(int I=1; I<=10; I++){
al.addView(btn+I);
}
```

I knew that this method will outcome wrong and it happened.
Please Answer what I should do.

Comment: tried with for ( <iterate> ) { new Button(); } ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new button each time the loop executes. So try it like this.

```
AbsoluteLayout al = …………

for(int I=1; I<=10; I++){

  Button btn = new Button(MyActivity.this);
  btn.setId(I);
  btn.setWidth(20);
  btn.setHeight(6);
  al.addView(btn);
}
```

Comment: Not Working. Please Give any solution which works correctly.

Comment: Is there an error message? If there is please post as a comment.

Comment: Can I be connected with you by FaceBook or Twitter.Please give me your username.